# QML ParentChange transition animation issue

Tags: qt, qml

I am not sure if this is a bug in Qt or it's how it should work, but here is a struggle i have:

First, the code that works how i expect it to work:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

  Item {

      width: 200; height: 100
      objectName: "Item"

      Rectangle {
          id: redRect
          objectName: "Red rectangle"
          width: 100; height: 100
          color: "red"
      }

      Rectangle {
          id: blueRect
          objectName: "Blue rectangle"
          x: redRect.width
          width: 50; height: 50
          color: "blue"

          property bool selected: false

          states: State {
              when: blueRect.selected
              name: "reparented"
              ParentChange {
                  target: blueRect
                  parent: redRect
                  width: 10
                  height: 10
              }
          }

          transitions: [
              Transition {
                  from: "*"
                  to: "reparented"

                  ParallelAnimation{
                      ParentAnimation{
                          NumberAnimation{
                              properties: "width, height"
                              duration: 400
                          }
                      }
                      }
                  }
          ]

          onParentChanged: console.log("Parent now is :", parent.objectName)

          MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: blueRect.selected = !blueRect.selected}//blueRect.state = "reparented" }
      }
  }
```

When clicking on a blue rectangle, it gets reparented to a Red rectangle. The console output is:

```
qml: Parent now is : Item   <--- When component created
qml: Parent now is : Red rectangle   <--- Reparenting when rectangle was clicked.
```

I found two cases when reparenting behaves differently. First, if in `ParentChange{...}` `x` or `y` properties are set as a function that returns value:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

  Item {

      width: 200; height: 100
      objectName: "Item"

      Rectangle {
          id: redRect
          objectName: "Red rectangle"
          width: 100; height: 100
          color: "red"
      }

      Rectangle {
          id: blueRect
          objectName: "Blue rectangle"
          x: redRect.width
          width: 50; height: 50
          color: "blue"

          property bool selected: false

          function someFunc() {return 10} // <------ add this line

          states: State {
              when: blueRect.selected
              name: "reparented"
              ParentChange {
                  target: blueRect
                  parent: redRect
                  width: someFunc()    // <--- change here
                  height: someFunc()   // <--- chaghe here
              }
          }

          transitions: [
              Transition {
                  from: "*"
                  to: "reparented"

                  ParallelAnimation{
                      ParentAnimation{
                          NumberAnimation{
                              properties: "width, height"
                              duration: 400
                          }
                      }
                      }
                  }
          ]

          onParentChanged: console.log("Parent now is :", parent.objectName)

          MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: blueRect.selected = !blueRect.selected}//blueRect.state = "reparented" }
      }
  }
```

And another case is when there is an Anchor change involved. For example:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

  Item {

      width: 200; height: 100
      objectName: "Item"

      Rectangle {
          id: redRect
          objectName: "Red rectangle"
          width: 100; height: 100
          color: "red"
      }

      Rectangle {
          id: blueRect
          objectName: "Blue rectangle"
          x: redRect.width
          width: 50; height: 50
          color: "blue"

          property bool selected: false

          states: State {
              when: blueRect.selected
              name: "reparented"
              ParentChange {
                  target: blueRect
                  parent: redRect
                  width: 10
                  height: 10
              }
              AnchorChanges {
                  target: blueRect
                  anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                  anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
              }
          }

          transitions: [
              Transition {
                  from: "*"
                  to: "reparented"

                  ParallelAnimation{
                      ParentAnimation{
                          NumberAnimation{
                              properties: "width, height"
                              duration: 400
                          }
                      }
                      AnchorAnimation {
                          duration: 400
                      }
                      }
                  }
          ]

          onParentChanged: console.log("Parent now is :", parent.objectName)

          MouseArea { anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: blueRect.selected = !blueRect.selected}//blueRect.state = "reparented" }
      }
  }
```

In both, second and third cases the output is:

```
qml: Parent now is : Item   <--- When component is created
qml: Parent now is : Red rectangle   <--- Here is after blue rectangle is clicked
qml: Parent now is : Item   <--- Now this is where it gets glitchy. Blue rectangle gets reparented back to Item
qml: Parent now is : Red rectangle   <--- And now it gets reparented to a Red rectangle back, as i would expect.
```

Because of this issue, inside of `AnchorChanges{}` the value returned for `parent.vertical/horizontalCenter` is the `Item` when i would expect it to be `Red rectangle`

So my question is: What could cause this effect, and is this a normal behavior, or it is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a related bug report, so this question can be closed now.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16727

**Edit:**

Also, this behavior is described in qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html#state-fast-forwarding) as:

> **State Fast Forwarding**
>
> In order for Transition to correctly animate state changes, it is
>   sometimes necessary for the engine to fast forward and rewind a state
>   (that is, internally set and unset the state) before it is finally
>   applied. The process is as follows:
>
> 1. The state is fast forwarded to determine the complete set of end values.
> 2. The state is rewound.
> 3. The state is fully applied, with transitions.
>
> In some cases this may cause unintended behavior. For example, a state
>   that changes a view's model or a `Loader's` `sourceComponent` will set
>   these properties multiple times (to apply, rewind, and then reapply),
>   which can be relatively expensive.
>
> State fast forwarding should be considered an implementation detail,
>   and may change in later versions.

Comment: Thank you. I have been puzzled by similar effects.